# Leaving DispatchGroup causes my code to crash

Tags: arrays, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I've got the following function but it keeps crashing on the 
dispatchGroup.leave() statement and I don't understand why. Based on what I found online every dispatchGroup.leave() must be associated with a dispatchGroup.enter() which I believe is the case for my function.

self.kycRecords only contains 1 element (for now) btw.

```
 @IBAction func checkCustomerList(_ sender: Any) {
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for kycRecord in self.kycRecords {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            ApiManager.sharedInstance.postUserToArtemis(kycRecord) {(response, error) in
                dispatchGroup.leave()
                if error != nil {
                    kycRecord.kycStatus = "failed"
                } else {
                    if response == true {
                        kycRecord.kycStatus = "passed"
                    } else {
                        kycRecord.kycStatus = "failed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
            print("done")
            self.writeOutput()
        })
    }
```

It crashes with the message:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

[image]

Comment: Provide details about the crash.

Comment: _How_ does it crash? Is there an error message or something available?

Comment: Added some more info to the post

Comment: Try putting the `for` loop inside a background queue: `DispatchQueue.global().async { for .. { ... } }`

Comment: @rmaddy I've tried that but now my self.writeOutput() is triggered before the loop finishes again.

Comment: Move the "notify" inside the background queue too.

Comment: Still crashes. Xcode is giving me the same message

Comment: When it crashes, click the "play" button a few times until you see a full error and stacktrace in the debugger console. What's the error message?

Comment: Pressing the play button doesn't seem to print anymore logging anywhere, pressed it about 30 times.

Comment: Anything I can do to pull out more logging? Can't seem to resolve this issue.

Comment: Found it... My API call was sending 2 completion handlers

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans Your comment saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check number of count entered in group before leaving from any group 
by below **Patch Work**

```
let count = self.groupExecuting.debugDescription.components(separatedBy: ",").filter({$0.contains("count")}).first!.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).filter({Int($0) != nil})
```